# qooxdoo 3.5/4.0 : how to upload a file

Tags: qooxdoo

I am creating a form using Qooxdoo framework with a file upload functionality.

but I am not able to understand how I can get this.

I got some links like : [uploadWidget](http://qooxdoo.org/contrib/project/uploadmgr)

but I am not sure they will work with the newer version of qooxdoo(3.5/4.0).

can anybody tell me how I can do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Qooxdoo only wraps what is already available via JS. File upload from JS has historically been tricky and restricted, since it's a sensitive operation from a security point of view.

Your best bet is to use the contrib. The only alternative you have is to hack together something similar yourself - sort of reinventing the wheel. IME contribs are usualy well maintained across qooxdoo versions.